# How do I return Cloudant insert status?

Tags: node.js, async-await, cloudant

I have the following code:

```
updateDocument = (data) => {
   Cloudant(CONN_STRING, (err, cloudant) => {
    if (err) {
        throw new Error('Failed to initialize Cloudant: ' + err.message);
    }

    let db = cloudant.db.use('my-db')

    db.insert(data, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            throw new Error('Failed to initialize Cloudant: ' + err.message);
        }
        else {
            console.log(result);
        }
    })
  });
}
```

I would like for `updateDocument()` to return the result db.insert provides. However, if I try to return a variable it is undefined (I believe because of the async calls). I've tried `async` and `await`, but I may not have set them up properly because they also didn't work.

**Thanks for any help!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a "JavaScript is asynchronous" problem. You could simplify your `updateDocument` function like so:

```
updateDocument = (data) => {
   var cloudant = Cloudant({ url: CONN_STRING, plugin: 'promises');
   let db = cloudant.db.use('my-db')
   return db.insert(data);
}
```

This is using the Cloudant library with the "promises" plugin. JavaScript Promises help you manage asynchronous calls without passing callback functions around.

You would call this code like so:

```
updateDocument({a: 1, :b})
  .then((data) => {
    console.log('success!', data);
  }.catch((e) => {
    console.log('oops!', e);
  });
```

Success arrives at 'then', failure arrives in the 'catch' clause.